# Vuetify autocomplete's select menu, set a class to each of the menu's items

Tags: javascript, vuetify.js

I am using Vuetify's v-autocomplete component.
I need to capture the click event when a user clics a value in the select menu (values suggested from the autocomplete's search).

Once a value is selected by the user, i can then trigger another function from within a D3.js force graph in a distant component.

What I had in mind is , to set a class name to each of the elements in the select menu and then be able to select those items and trigger a function on clic (from within my D3 svg) such as:

```
      d3.selectAll(".autocomplete-vals").on("click", function () {
        console.log('Yay! it works!')
      });
```

Now what is holding me back is that I have no idea how I can set the class names to the select menu items. The select menu seems nested within the autocomplete component.

Here is my current v-autocomplete :

```
        <v-autocomplete
            v-model="valuesActor"
            :items="actorArray"
            :search-input.sync="searchActor"
            filled
            autofocus
            mutliple
            @blur="toggleSearch"
            background-color="#313131"
            append-icon=""
            prepend-inner-icon="mdi-arrow-left"
            color="var(--textLightGrey)"
            :menu-props="{maxWidth: 1600}"
            placeholder="Search for actors"
        >
        </v-autocomplete>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out a walkarround.

I make a watcher in order to monitor changes on valuesActor.
Then I created a dom element (in my case it is a span) with an id/class of "simClick".
When valuesActor changes value, it triggers a function that will programatically simulate a click on the new span such as :

```
let aa = document.querySelector("#simClic")
aa.click()
```

Finally, from inside my D3.js function that creates a forcegraph, I target the span element and then execute my zoom function uppon click such as :

```
   d3.select(".simClic").on("click", function () {
        svg.transition().duration(750).call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity);
   });
```

I am sure this isn't the best way to do this. but for now it works